# Android Studio Not Recognizing Imports in TextView

Tags: android-studio

I want to watch android sources code, but Android Studio has so many errors in base Android code. How do I fix these?

[image: Errors in Adroid Studio]

Comment: In short, you have to resolve your dependencies.

Comment: thank you ,i will have a try.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has jumped in here to help with this...

The longer answer here is that the imports (in red) are failing because Android Studio can't find them.  So all the calls made to those libraries are failing.  So ALL your code after that is full of errors.

For instance, the android.annotation.ColorInt seems to be broken.  A quick Google search provides THIS:  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/ColorInt.html

Which tells me that the reason that dependency is broken is because whatever you have there is deprecated and should now use a new reference.

Continue with this sort of research and your problem is solved.